# How to write retention policy in marklogic server to segregate current version from its older versions into different collections?

Tags: marklogic

I have been trying to write a retention policy using Marklogic `dls:retention-rule`. The problem is `dls:retention-rule` provides options to retain versions or delete, in my case I want to retain old versions but in different collection. Say a document has 5 older versions. I want 5 old versions to be in collection1 and the current version to be in collection2.

How do I achieve this using retention policy. If not retention policy is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already found out, retention policies only govern document retention.

It sounds to me like you could write a CPF pipeline to do what you want. In the pipeline you would check the property `dls:version-id` to see which collections to set on the document. The pipeline would update the document collections directly, bypassing the DLS functions.

http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http%3a//pubs/5.0doc/xml/cpf/title.xml has documentation on CPF and custom pipelines.